# Highlight all railway lines in Google Map Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a small web page using Google Map Api and I want to highlight all railway lines in Google Map Api.

I've tried with [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) but maybe It doesn't has Map Features for Railway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature type `transit.lines` might be what you are looking for.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

But it includes more than only railway lines (I suppose subway, boat, etc.) but that still might help depending on what you are trying to do...

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/vgdqwos0/)</kbd>

```js
function initialize() {

    // Create an array of styles.
    var styles = [{
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit.line",
            "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 100
        }, {
            "color": "#ff3183"
        }]
    }];

    // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles, as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
        name: "Styled Map"
    });

    // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add to the map type control.
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7288, -74.1509),
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, 'map_style']
        }
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    // Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an simple way to create the map that you can create your own google map so as what you can define on google map. Here through this link you can create your own google map that what you want to do on google map:

https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024454?hl=en&amp%3Bref_topic=3188329

[google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csz15.png)

just click on three dots and select the option embed map then after clicking an html tag will generate you have to just copy paste in your project and your google map is ready according to your desire